# Eclipse Indexer don't work

Tags: c, eclipse, indexer

I'm using Eclipse 6 with c/c++  ide.

I have a existing project from a colleague. So i started a new project and imported 
the file system.

I got this error message and the indexer is not working.

But I have no clue what to do.

An internal error occurred during: "C/C++ Indexer".
org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.pdom.PDOMProxy cannot be cast to org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.index.IWritableIndexFragment

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43494698/3868696) seems to have solved my issue.

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
   1) Go into your eclipse project properties
   2) in left panel->c/c++ General
   3) in right panel->configure work space setting
   4) in left panel->expand c/c++
   5) in left panel click on indexer 
   6) in select indexer-> choose no indexer
```

This is temporary solution and i say its inappropriate if you want to use search for some predefined keyword or functions

But to get going you can try this.